# Help! android device manager... will enable lock & erase appear after resetting the device?

Tags: android-device-manager

I lost my phone, it's an LG G2 Verizon, it wasn't factory reset and when I go to ADM it showed the device with the options of Lock and Erase separately... At first I locked it, but then I erased it, and I received an email from the ADM saying ( Android Device Manager will try to erase the data on your Android device and SD card. If the data is successfully erased, your device will display the Android Welcome screen the next time it's turned on. ) after moments both buttons disappeared and I only had one option which is Ring or Enable lock & erase, so does that mean that my device has been reset ? trying to get the phone back but at the same time I don't want my private things to be in the wrong hands.. thank you in advance!

Comment: No, if and when your device is reset it and ADM is notified it occurred (it should), then you will get an email stating the date, time, and approximate location of the device when the reset occurred.

Comment: But why did the options change ? And the device is no longer online since I did the reset and received the email, also the location on that phone is not activated

Comment: Odd... I wonder if it is an Android version thing. I tested it with my spare device though (Moto G 2015 on Marshmallow), I did NOT get a confirmation email that the wipe occurred, but it did wipe. I sent the command while the device was off, turned it on, and 30 seconds later it rebooted and did a factory reset. Even after the reset occurred I still had the normal Ring, Lock, and Erase buttons in ADM.

Comment: I remember that the LG had android 5.0

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that all the data is deleted. But after you reset the phone, if the **location** is turned on, then only you will get the exact location on map. Otherwise, you cannot get the location.